# PHP: get a single key from object

Tags: php, object

I have an object with a single key and its value. But I don't know the key to access it. What is the most efficient way to get the key without enumerating the object?

Comment: So how do you know you've got the right key?

Comment: Are you looking to do an `array_search`?

Comment: I have just a single json object converted to php like `{"foo":3}` and I need to take both, key name and value.

Comment: If you're decoding the JSON yourself, you can decode it into an associative array and make your life slightly easier. `json_decode($json, true)`.

Comment: The thing is I really can't change the decode mode. Example I brought was just a leaf in hierarchy.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you just want to *access the value*, you don't need the key (actually *property name*) at all:

```
$value = current((array)$object);
```

If you really want the *property name*, try this:

```
$key = key((array)$object);
```

Comment: I have an array of objects and the objects have one property each, and I don't know the names of the properties. I am iterating through the array using `foreach` loop, and for each object, I want the key as well as value. I have found this solution, but isn't it inefficient because you are casting the $object to an array each time? (Sorry if it is too basic, but I am a newb. An answer will be greatly appreciated, as I am not sure whether it is wise to use this or not)..

Comment: This answer saved my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
$array = array("foo" => "bar");

$keys = array_keys($array);

echo $keys[0];

// Output: foo
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: This really works for an object? `stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'tag1' => 1,
))`

Comment: @Michael: My mistake, I assumed you were attempting to retrieve the key from an array. In which case, you will want to cast the object to an array most likely. See @thomasrutter's example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411495/php-get-a-single-key-from-object/3411520#3411520

Comment: I was initially misled as well by the use of the word "key", which is an array term...

Answer (score 7):

You can cast the object to an array like this:

```
$myarray = (array)$myobject;
```

And then, for an array that has only a single value, this should fetch the key for that value.

```
$value = key($myarray);
```

You could do both those in one line if you like.  Of course, you could also do it by enumerating the object, like you mentioned in your question.

To get the value rather than the key, then:

```
$value = current($myarray);
```