# Retrieve elements of JSON with php

Tags: php, json

I got a JSON from a web site in the raw format:

```
{
    "A_B" : {
        "id" : 7,
        "last" : "0.00000038"
    },
    "A_C" : {
        "id" : 8,
        "last" : "0.00001938"
    },
    ...
}
```

From that I got an unique array `$c` with all `"A_B", ...`

I cannot find the right syntax to get the value for `'id', 'last'` within the key `c[0]`.

Comment: Kindly include the codes of what you've already tried

Comment: You wish to get the id of `A_B` or id of all the elements?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411527/5039470

Answer (score 2):

A basic PHP example:

```php
$raw = '{
        "A_B" : {
            "id" : 7,
            "last" : "0.00000038"
        },
        "A_C" : {
            "id" : 8,
            "last" : "0.00001938"
        }
    }';

// Translate from JSON to data object
$data = json_decode($raw);

// Read variables from the data object
echo 'Option 1)<br />
data->A_B->id = '.$data->A_B->id.'<br />
data->A_B->last = '.$data->A_B->last.'<br />';

// Extract and read a single object 
$c = $data->A_B;
echo 'Option 2)<br />
c->id = '.$c->id.'<br />
c->last = '.$c->last.'<br />';

// To an array version. Note: 'true' is included
$ar = json_decode($raw, true);

// Reading a array 
echo 'Option 3)<br />
ar[A_B][id] = '.$ar['A_B']['id'].'<br />
ar[A_B][last] = '.$ar['A_B']['last'].'<br />';

// And finally, I think what you have done
$c = $ar['A_B'];

echo 'Option 4)<br />
c[id] = '.$c['id'].'<br />
c[last] = '.$c['last'].'<br />';
```

Which will render the following:

```
Option 1)
data->A_B->id = 7
data->A_B->last = 0.00000038
Option 2)
c->id = 7
c->last = 0.00000038
Option 3)
ar[A_B][id] = 7
ar[A_B][last] = 0.00000038
Option 4)
c[id] = 7
c[last] = 0.00000038
```

**Edit**. I think I understand what you are after. See the following updated PHP script.

```php
$raw = '{
    "A_B" : {
        "id" : 7,
        "last" : "0.00000038"
    },
    "A_C" : {
        "id" : 8,
        "last" : "0.00001938"
    }
}';

// Only interested in these valves from the JSON
// Value 'X_Y`' is expected to fail!
$knownId = array('A_C','X_Y');

// Extract JSON to array
$c = json_decode($raw,true);

// Only print values that match $knownId
foreach($knownId as $k => $v) {
    if ($c[$v]) {
        echo '<p>v:['.$v.'] 
             id:['.$c[$v]['id'].'] 
             last:['.$c[$v]['last'].']</p>';
    }
}
```

Which would display a single result from the sample data in `$raw`.

```
v:[A_C] id:[8] last:[0.00001938]
```

Comment: The problem is that "A_C", "A_D", "B_C" ....  are (the only) elements of the unique array $c.

Comment: @RonaldWiplinger I think I know what you want now. See edited answer.

Comment: @RonaldWiplinger : Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

try this assuming you got your array by json_decode($jsnstr,true)

```
 $id = $c[0]["id"];
 $last = $c[0]["last"];
```

you can also use it in a for loop and using loop index i as array index

Comment: I think this assumes you decode it as an array and not an object, but that might not be obvious to person asking question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Using following you can get the value of "id" and "last"

```
$json_raw = '{
    "A_B" : {
        "id" : 7,
        "last" : "0.00000038"
    },
    "A_C" : {
        "id" : 8,
        "last" : "0.00001938"
    }
}';

//decode the json 
$data = json_decode($json_raw);


$c = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    //collect the keys
    $c[] = $key;
}

$c = array_unique($c);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {

    //check the key is exist
    if(in_array($key, $c)){

        // do computation
        $id = $value->id;
        $last = $value->last;

        echo "Key is :".$key."  , id :".$id." , last :".$last."\n";
    }


}
```

Output

```
Key is :A_B  , id :7 , last :0.00000038
Key is :A_C  , id :8 , last :0.00001938
```

Comment: Json gives me 1000 data, but I have already selected the ones I need. These keys are in the unique array $c. $c contains e.g., "A_B", "A_C", "F_D", ... All solutions here assume, that I have A_B, but it's a variable, stored in an array. Each of these will be worked on to put into a database.

Comment: sorry i am not able to understand the problem, can you please explain

Comment: json_raw has 1000 dates, all starting with something "A_B", "A_C", "F_D" ... In my first run, I extracted the keys I actually only need, that are now 50. These 50 dates I want to insert into a database. However, all solutions I found assume, that I use hard coded "A_B" instead of the collected 50 keys, stored in a unique array (I called it $c)

Comment: in that case instead of extracting u can also insert there only. if u dont mind please share ur code it will easier to understand

Comment: $b=array();
array_push($b,'A_B');
array_push($b,'A_C');
array_push($b,'A_B');
...
$c = array_unique($b);

From these elements of the array $c I want the values id and last

Comment: i have update the code base from on understanding , it might be useful

Comment: if possible i request you to mark the Ans correct, so that we can close this